# bootstrap "control-label" behaves strange when following dynamically created list

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, label, html-lists, stylesheet

```
<!-- code snippet of html -->

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="items" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Items</label>
    <div class="pull-left input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addNewItem()">Add</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="pull-left">
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <p style="display: inline-block">{{item}}</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="deleteItem(item)">Delete</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="anotherField" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Another Field</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="anotherField" id="anotherField">
</div>

/* code snippet in Augular controller */
  $scope.addNewItem = function() {
      if ($scope.name && $scope.name.trim()) {
          if ($scope.items.indexOf($scope.name.trim()) >= 0) {
              console.log('item name should not be duplicated');
          } else {
              $scope.items.push($scope.name.trim());
              $scope.name = '';
          }
      }
  };

  $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
      var idx = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
      if (idx >= 0) $scope.items.splice(idx, 1);
  };
```

Above codes function properly, but the only problem is that when I create even on one new item, the label supposedly for "anotherField" just shows up immediately after this this very item (even misaligned with the label for "items"); when more items were created, it's simply placed at the end of the 1st item but not like a label for "anotherField" any more.  Anybody can help to address this "strange" style issue?

Thanks,
Xihua